# Strange error in facebook SDK login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm searching for a solution without any result...

I've correctly installed PHP library for facebook, create an application with ID and secret code, created page php and work until confirm access with facebook account, show this error:

(Callback url)
Graph returned an error: Impossibile caricare l'URL: Il dominio di questo URL non Ã¨ incluso nei domini dell'app. Per poter caricare questo URL, aggiungi tutti i domini e i sottodomini della tua app al campo Domini app nelle tue impostazioni app.

Unable to load URL because is missing in url domain....but is false!

Here my APP configurations
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S31Kc.jpg)

```
This is config php 
------------------------------------
$appId          = '20386911XXXXXXX'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret      = '1441a5f9dXXXXXXXXXXXXXc03aae06'; //Facebook App Secret
$redirectURL    = 'http_MY_WEB_SITE_/facebook_login_with_php/'; //Callback 
URL
$fbPermissions  = array('email');  //Optional permissions
------------------------------------
```

And this is the result in callback url:

### http://www.makewish.it/facebook_login_with_php/?code=AQBRhvLnJWwNAMIKa5b..(etc)

### Graph returned an error: URL kann nicht geladen werden: Die Domain dieser URL ist nicht in den Domains der App vorhanden. Um diese URL laden zu können, füge alle Domains und Subdomains deiner App im Appdomain-Feld in deinen App-Einstellungen hinzu.

In my VALID OAuth I have
http_MY_WEB_SITE_/facebook_login_with_php/

Why this problem?  How I can resolve? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same! Code connects fine to the FB login page but on the callback, I am getting this error in GERMAN language...???

After some time, I found a solution, I needed to define the redirect url explicit in $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

So I changed:

$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

to

$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken('https://...[my redirect url]')

And this solved the issue for me.

Here is my full solution in small steps (without code optimalization, but just to make the steps simpler to understand:

**LOGIN PAGE:**

```
if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
}

// Include the autoloader provided in the SDK
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk/autoload.php';

// Include required libraries
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

/*
 * Configuration and setup Facebook SDK
 */
$appId          = 'fill in yours'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret      = 'fill in yours'; //Facebook App Secret
$redirectURL    = 'https://fill in yours/get-user-back.php'; //Callback URL
$fbPermissions  = array('email');  //Optional permissions

$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'app_id' => $appId,
    'app_secret' => $appSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
));

// Get redirect login helper
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

// Get login url
$loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $fbPermissions);

// next make a button with $loginURL
```

**RETURN PAGE:**

echo "Back from FB
";

if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
}

// Include the autoloader provided in the SDK
require_once **DIR** . '/facebook-php-sdk/autoload.php';

// Include required libraries
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

/*
 * Configuration and setup Facebook SDK
 */
$appId          = 'fill in yours'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret      = 'fill in yours'; //Facebook App Secret
$redirectURL    = 'https://fill in yours/get-user-back.php'; //Callback URL
$fbPermissions  = array('email');  //Optional permissions

$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'app_id' => $appId,
    'app_secret' => $appSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
));

// Get redirect login helper
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken('https://fill in yours/get-user-back.php');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
    if ($helper->getError()) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
        echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
        echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
        echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
        echo 'Bad request';
    }
    exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {

```
// OAuth 2.0 client handler helps to manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
    echo "<HR>accesToken is not LongLived<HR>";
    // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
    try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
    }   
}

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);

echo "<HR>";

// Getting user facebook profile info
try {
    $profileRequest = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture');
    $fbUserProfile = $profileRequest->getGraphNode()->asArray();


} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    session_destroy();
    // Redirect user back to app login page
    header("Location: ./");
    exit;
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($fbUserProfile); echo '</pre>';
```

}